# The build validation for PR has started when I do a merge in ADO

Tags: merge, yaml, azure-pipelines, ado, pull-request

I have a sprint95 branch in Azure DevOps, in this branch I have configured Build Validation with my pipeline from a yml file that validates the code before pull request to the sprint95 branch.
[image]
However, there is a problem that this `pr-unit-test-approvement` check is triggered just as soon as the merge happens (e.g. into the master branch or another branch).
[image]

Or other example (this all from list pr-unit-test-approvement pipeline)
[image]

I've spent a day and a half, but still haven't found what would make the code check setup for pull request for merge start.
Please help with some advice. How to exclude merge validation?

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear on the circumstances under which you're seeing the pipeline triggering and your desired behavior. Show the `triggers` section in your YAML. If there's no `triggers` section, the implicit trigger is "on any commit" -- review the documentation.

Comment: My repository is in ADO, if I'm not mistaken I don't need a trigger in the nd file?

I would like the pipeline "pr-unit-test-approvement" to run only when a PR is made in the sprint95 branch. And that there would be no false positives when merging into a master branch, for example

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest
variables:
  NetVersion: '6'
  BuildConfiguration: Release

steps:

- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET $(NetVersion).x sdk '
  inputs:
    version: $(NetVersion).x
    includePreviewVersions: true
```

Comment: Then set `trigger: none` in your pipeline. The default behavior when the `trigger` section is omitted is to trigger on *every commit*. Again, **review the documentation if you're not clear on behavior**, because this is explicitly stated.

Comment: Thank you @DanielMann, yes, new parameter trigger: none in yml file was helped

Answer (score 0):

Per this build in the screenshot, it was triggered by `CI` - the commit `3cee7485` pushed to the `master` branch rather than the PR from Branch `Spint95`. As soon as the code of a PR (`2952`) was merged into the target branch `master`, it pushed a commit (`3cee7485`) onto the target branch.
[image]

And if any of your pipelines' reference `.yml` file from `master` branch enables `CI` trigger, it will be triggered by any commit (including merge commit) pushed to `master`.
[image]

If you don’t want this pipeline to be triggered by commits pushed to `master` branch, please disable the `CI` trigger in the reference `.yml` file from `master` branch by updating `trigger: none`. But this can only take effect on `master` branch **not** all branches. You can use PR to spread this update of the `.yml` files onto other branches.

[image]

As another convenient option, you may use the pipeline's trigger settings in web UI to override the YAML `CI` trigger and to disable `CI` trigger for all branches or enable `CI` trigger for selected branch(es).
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Alvin Zhao Yes, the idea was to add a parameter to the yml file parameter trigger: none